# Make NetworkX node attributes into Pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I have a `Networkx graph` called `G` created below:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1,job= 'teacher', boss = 'dee')
G.add_node(2,job= 'teacher', boss = 'foo')
G.add_node(3,job= 'admin', boss = 'dee')
G.add_node(4,job= 'admin', boss = 'lopez')
```

I would like to store the `node` number along with `attributes`, `job` and `boss` in separate columns of a `pandas` `dataframe`.

I have attempted to do this with the below code but it produces a `dataframe` with 2 columns, 1 with `node` number and one with all of the `attributes`:

```
graph = G.nodes(data = True)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(graph)

df
Out[19]: 
    0                                      1
0  1  {u'job': u'teacher', u'boss': u'dee'}
1  2  {u'job': u'teacher', u'boss': u'foo'}
2  3    {u'job': u'admin', u'boss': u'dee'}
3  4  {u'job': u'admin', u'boss': u'lopez'}
```

Note: I acknowledge that `NetworkX` has a `to_pandas_dataframe` function but it does not provide a `dataframe` with the output I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how representative your data is but it should be straightforward to modify my code to work on your real network:

```
In [32]:
data={}
data['node']=[x[0] for x in graph]
data['boss'] = [x[1]['boss'] for x in graph]
data['job'] = [x[1]['job'] for x in graph]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1

Out[32]:
    boss      job  node
0    dee  teacher     1
1    foo  teacher     2
2    dee    admin     3
3  lopez    admin     4
```

So here all I'm doing is constructing a dict from the graph data, pandas accepts dicts as data where the keys are the column names and the data has to be array-like, in this case lists of values

A more dynamic method:

```
In [42]:
def func(graph):
    data={}
    data['node']=[x[0] for x in graph]
    other_cols = graph[0][1].keys()
    for key in other_cols:
        data[key] = [x[1][key] for x in graph]
    return data
pd.DataFrame(func(graph))

Out[42]:
    boss      job  node
0    dee  teacher     1
1    foo  teacher     2
2    dee    admin     3
3  lopez    admin     4
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The only part of the solution I do not understand is the `x[0] for x in graph`. I understand that `graph` is a `list` but what is happening in `x[0]` of `x` in `graph`?

Comment: You have a list of tuples, the first element in the tuple is the node value, hence `x[0]` the second element is a dict `x[1]`

Comment: There is a mistake. It should be `def func(graph):`.

Answer (score 29):

Here's a one-liner.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(graph.nodes(data=True)), orient='index')
```

Comment: This is the more pythonic answer.

Comment: This does not work though if nodes have no attributes, then you get an empty DataFrame out.

Comment: @Mitar what would be the expected output for a graph with no attributes? A dataframe with only index?

Comment: Yes, ideally only index then.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is even simpler:

```
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(graph.nodes, orient='index')
```

Without having to convert to another dict.

Comment: This does not work though if nodes have no attributes, then you get an empty DataFrame out.

Comment: I know this answer came 2 years late, but it should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I updated this solution to work with my updated version of NetworkX (2.0) and thought I would share. I also had the function return a Pandas DataFrame.

```
def nodes_to_df(graph):
    import pandas as pd
    data={}
    data['node']=[x[0] for x in graph.nodes(data=True)]
    other_cols = graph.nodes[0].keys()
    for key in other_cols:
        data[key] = [x[1][key] for x in graph.nodes(data=True)]
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with a `dictionary comprehension`.

```
d = {n:dag.nodes[n] for n in dag.nodes}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

Your dictionary `d` maps the nodes `n` to `dag.nodes[n]`.
Each value of that dictionary `dag.nodes[n]` is a dictionary itself and contains all attributes: `{attribute_name:attribute_value}`

So your dictionary `d` has the form:

```
{node_id : {attribute_name : attribute_value} }
```

The advantage I see is that you do not need to know the names of your attributes.

If you wanted to have the node-IDs not as index but in a column, you could add as the last command:

```
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```